# It is possible to edit some config with HTTP API in HAProxy

Tags: haproxy

I using the community edition of HAProxy (version 2.5). In fact, I want to dynamically change some config for example enable or disable some servers.

I read the document and the only thing I found was  :‌

- Data Plane API
- Runtime API (execute a command through the command line )

but I Don't find anything like HTTP API. Is there a way or tool that can help me?

Answer (score 0):

I'm just getting started with the HAProxy API so I don't have in-depth help but the Data Plane API should provide what you need.

Follow the setup here: https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/hapee/latest/api/data-plane-api/installation/haproxy-community/